Authorization error when uploading blob with managed indetity
I am trying to upload a simple blob from an azure function app with managed identity:
public class BlobUtil
{
    static public async Task UploadBlob(string accountName, string containerName, string blobName, string blobContents)
    {
        // Construct the blob container endpoint from the arguments.
        string containerEndpoint = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}",
                                                    accountName,
                                                    containerName);

        // Get a credential and create a client object for the blob container.
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri(containerEndpoint),
                                                                        new DefaultAzureCredential());

        try
        {
            // Create the container if it does not exist.
            await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            // Upload text to a new block blob.
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(blobContents);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                await containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(blobName, stream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

await BlobUtil.UploadBlob("stintxxxxatadev", "xxx", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".json", "yo bro");

I get following error:

The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or
an application request

And

Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this
operation.)

The function has been provided following access on the storage account:

Am I missing some further access settings or any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

The role looks correct. Wondering if there is a network setting which might be blocking the access to the storage account.

I do agree with @Gaurav Mantri that the problem lies in networking. Below is my case of networking that works:

or if it is enabled with selective networks then you need to integrate with Virtual network for both Function app and storage account and also refer this SO-Thread1 and SO-Thread2.
And should give Storage Blob Contributor to Function app managed identity.
The code which worked for me:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.Text;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
public class TestFunc
{
    [Function("TestFunc")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest ri)
    {
        var ri_bsc = new BlobServiceClient(
            new Uri("https://rithwik.blob.core.windows.net"),
            new DefaultAzureCredential());
        string ri_con = "rithcont1";
        var ri_cc = ri_bsc.GetBlobContainerClient(ri_con);
        var ri_bn = "Test.txt";
        var test = "Hello Rithwik Bojja, The blob is created";
        var rbc = ri_cc.GetBlobClient(ri_bn);
        using (var rith = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test)))
        {
            await rbc.UploadAsync(rith, true);
        }
        return new OkObjectResult($"Hello Rithwik Bojja, The blob  with name '{ri_bn}'is created  and uploaded plz check.");
    }
}

Output:



Your were right. It was a network issue fixed by network department. Following it worked. Thanks for the input appreciated.

Glad it worked @ThomasSegato
